# SWIG/python - defined constants in C not accessible

Tags: python, swig

I'm using Swig 3.0.7 to create python 2.7-callable versions of C functions that define constants in this manner:

```c
#define MYCONST 5.0
```

In previous versions of swig these would be available to python transparently:

```py
import mymodule

x = 3. * mymodule.MYCONST
```

But now this generates a message

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MYCONST'
```

Functions in 'mymodule' that use the constant internally work as expected.

Interestingly, if I include this line in the Swig directive file mymodule.i,

```c
#define MYCONST 5.0
```

then doing dir(mymodule) returns a list that includes

```
['MYCONST_swigconstant', 'SWIG_PyInstanceMethodNew',  (etc.) .... ]
```

typing to the python interpreter

```
 mymodule.MYCONST_swigconstant
```

gives

```
<built-in function MYCONST_swigconstant>
```

which offers no obvious way to get at the value.

So my question is, can one make the previous syntax work so that `mymodule.MYCONST` evaluates correctly

If not, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Definitions are not exported to SWIG through `cvar`. You can do the following

```
#define MYCONST 5.0
const float gMYCONST = MYCONST;
```

In this way, you add type information to your constant and it can be accessed through

```
import mymodule
mymodule.cvar.gMYCONST
```

I have SWIG 3.0.2 and using this version, the definition can be accessed using `mymodule.MYCONST`, but for other reasons, I usually convert macro definitions to typed definitions.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your issue.  If the below demonstration doesn't help, post your build process:

test.i:

```
%module test
%inline %{
#define MYCONST 5.0
%}
```

Swig 3.0.8 and compiled with VS2012 into a C extension:

```
swig -python test.i
cl /MD /LD /Fe_test.pyd /Ic:\python33\include test_wrap.c -link /libpath:c:\python33\libs
```

Use:

```
Python 3.3.5 (v3.3.5:62cf4e77f785, Mar  9 2014, 10:35:05) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import test
>>> test.MYCONST
5.0
```